# why git log ends with strange tokens?

Tags: git

[image: git log like this]

as shown above, strange tokens append into the real commit message, and also, the soft link cloned by git also been changed with weird tokens like：

[image: soft link]

Is anyone knows what caused this?

Comment: Someone else recently reported the same issue. As far as I know it was never resolved.